# Simple git merge concept

Tags: git

Suppose i have to merge one branch into another.

My simplified concept concept is this:

- git looks at each file in each particular path and compares two files

  - git diffs files: if they are similar, everything is okay
  - if not, git tries to do a 3-way merge with both files

Is that correct conceptually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Given commits A and B to be merged, git doesn't compare A to B at all. What git thinks about is this:

Given where the two commits' history split, what did it take to get from the split point to commit A, and what did it take to get from the split point to commit B? Well, if possible, do *both* of those things.

In other words, git finds the commit S where the histories of A and B diverged, and gets the diff S -> A and diff S -> B and performs *both* diffs on S.

```
   diff1......
     /<------A
<- S 
     \<------B
   diff2......
```

In order to do that, it has to think about every file *in S* and apply the corresponding two diffs applied to it.

The result of applying both diffs to S is a new commit S' which has both A and B as its parents:

```
   diff1......
     /<------A <-\
<- S              S'
     \<------B <-/
   diff2......
```

Comment: What is if one file was not existent in that commit S, but was later introduced on both branches independently? (happens for example if you use bitbucket-pipelines.yml and commit it first on master and later independently on the develop branch).

Comment: One file cannot be introduced in two branches. Two files with the same name appeared in both diffs. That sounds like a conflict, eh.

Comment: Does the algorithm for rebase work in a similar fashion?

Comment: No but it too is about applying diffs.

Comment: Unfortunately, Git *doesn't* look at history from S-to-A and S-to-B, it just does a direct `git diff --find-renames` on the S-A and S-B pairs. (To handle renames better, I'd argue that it should look at the intermediate commits, or at least have a flag to do that. But it doesn't.)

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly right.

First, Git looks for the merge base, which is usually the latest common commit between the two commits you're merging.  That's what it will compare each of the heads (the commits you're merging) against.

It then compares the same file in each commit.  If the file is the same (that is, its object ID is identical), then Git just takes that as the result, since both sides have the same thing.

Then, it looks for renames to find files which may have been moved or copied.  Since we're looking for a simplified answer, we'll ignore these for now.

If the files are not completely identical, Git computes the differences between that file in the merge base and each head in turn.  It then produces a file which has both sets of differences, which is the three-way merge.  If it can do this successfully for every file, then your merge succeeds.  If a file has different changes in the same area on both sides, then a conflict occurs, which you then have to resolve manually.

As I've implied above, Git looks only at the merge base and the two heads and their respective differences, not any commits between them.  Whatever intermediate commits exist and their changes are irrelevant; all that matters is the state at the merge base and the two heads, not how they got there.